# Select2 sorter callback not being called

Tags: dropdown, jquery-select2

I can't get the Select2 (v 4.0.13) sorter callback to work when I have default values pre-selected.

This is how Select2 is initialized:

```
this._createCustomSelect(o, $("#my-select"));


_createCustomSelect = function(o, select)
    select.select2({
            placeholder: o.placeholder,
            multiple: o.multiSelect,
            closeOnSelect: !o.multiSelect,
            maximumSelectionLength: 10,
            resultsAdapter: $.fn.select2.amd.require("resultsAdapter"),
            sorter: data => data.sort((a, b) => a.text.localeCompare(b.text))
    });
```

After that I pre-fill the defaults:

```
if (document.readyState === "loading") {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        selectElement.select2().val(["X"]).trigger("change");
    });
 } else { ... }
```

But the sorting never happens.

If I do not prefill (that means I don't run the second code), sorting works just fine.

Any idea what is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it:

```
selectElement.select2().val(["X"]).trigger("change");
```

should be changed to:

```
selectElement.val(["X"]).trigger("change");
```